# SSIS VS2012 convert flat file Text to Boolean

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am trying to take data from a CSV and import the records into my database. I have an SSIS package that reads in the flat file, passes it through a data conversion and then sends it to the database.

[image]

[image]

The problem I am having is the field that has "True" "False" or blank needs to be converted to a Boolean. This package worked in the past but we have upgraded from SQL 2008 to SQL 2014 and taken the package from VS2008 to VS2012.

Error:

```
Error: 2015-09-15 23:00:03.23
Code: 0xC02020C5     
Source: Data Flow Task 1 Data Conversion 0 - 0 [2]     
Description: Data conversion failed while converting column "aginactive" 
             (192) to column "aginactive" (62).  The conversion returned 
             status value 2 and status text "The value could not be 
             converted because of a potential loss of data.".  
End Error  

Error: 2015-09-15 23:00:03.23
Code: 0xC0209029      
Source: Data Flow Task 1 Data Conversion 0 - 0 [2]     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The 
             "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].
             Columns[aginactive]" failed because error code 0xC020907F 
             occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 
             0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[aginactive]" 
             specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the 
             specified object of the specified component. There may be 
             error messages posted before this with more information
             about the failure.  
End Error   

Error: 2015-09-15 23:00:03.23     
Code: 0xC0047022     
Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     
Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput 
             method on component "Data Conversion 0 - 0" (2) failed with 
             error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion 
             Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from 
             the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, 
             but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to 
             stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this 
             with more information about the failure.  
End Error
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If errors are being thrown while running the package please post it, or post what transformation you are getting when running the package.

Comment: Do you have an error message or anything? Have you confirmed that the data in the file has not changed? Without that info it's kind of a blind guess.

Comment: I had added the error as reported by the SQL server running the job. The datafile as not changed at all, it remains the same as it did before the upgrade

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expression you are using in your data conversion component.

Comment: There is no expression, its a Data Conversion tool, I just tell it the fields and it does the conversion automatically

Comment: I have added an image of what the Data Conversion process is setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the Data Conversion Transformation, use a Derived Column Transformation.   Create a new Boolean column with an Inline IF, so that if the input value is "True" it outputs 1, else 0.   Then use the new column in your destination.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try